# Include Bootstrap glyphs in Laravel Collective link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

I'm using Laravel Collective's `link_to_route()` method to create a link. I want to include a Bootstrap glyph with this link.

As it is now, it's printing the actual Html code.

Any tips on how to do this?

My current code:

```
<div class="col-lg-1 well">
    {!! link_to_route('companiesindex', "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-log-in' aria-hidden='true'></span> Companies") !!}
</div>
```

As a side question, is it normal to include the glyph in the actual link, or would this normally be before or after?

Answer (score 0):

There are few packages you can use,

- https://github.com/patricktalmadge/bootstrapper 
  https://github.com/bradcornford/Bootstrapper
  Using these you can easily get rid from thousands of HTML in your views

Comment: This basically includes bootstrap and related files. I'm not sure this answers my question.